# cURL POST request with bearer token results in "Could not resolve host: POST"

Tags: bash, curl, zsh

I'm issuing the following command in `zsh` to send a POST request with a bearer token.

```
curl -o -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" http://localhost:8090/services/item/0
```

The output I get is the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
```

---

## Update 1

I posted a wrong command which I have corrected now. This is what I'm issuing:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" http://localhost:8090/services/item/0
```

I discovered that the behavior is probably related to running the command in a ZSH. When using Bash the call works fine.

Comment: Can you share more details? Where did you define the request type in the given call? Why did you use `-o` without specifying the output file?

Comment: `curl` sends `GET` requests by default; you  need to use `curl -X POST` to make a `POST` request.

Comment: I don't see how the code you've posted could think `POST` is the host to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter that follows `-o` is a file name. Your command line begins with:

```
curl -o -X POST
```

... which then means that it will save the output to a file named `-X`. Then the following word (`POST`) will be treated as a URL since it doesn't start with a dash...

Using that URL (or host name rather) then causes this error:

```
Could not resolve host: POST
```

... because curl fails to resolve that host name. It seems there's no host in your network with that name!

Answer (score 0):

I check must work:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" http://localhost:8090/services/item/0
```

Or:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" http://localhost:8090/services/item/0 -o output.txt
```